# How can I use view resolver to return mobile or normal view?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-mobile

I have a web app and I want add the mobile version to it..

So I followed [this guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-mobile/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/device.html) to add spring-mobile, but I can't get my mobile views..

I don't want add in every controller's methods this piece of code:

```
if (device.isMobile()) {
  return "mobile/myPage.jspx";
} else if (device.isTablet()) {
  return "tablet/myPage.jspx";
} else {
  return "myPage.jspx";
}
```

So I'm trying to set a view-resolver to get the right page.
I use Tiles and this is its configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver" id="tilesViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>
```

And then I add this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.view.LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver">
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
  <property name="tabletPrefix" value="tablet/" />
</bean>
```

But my we-app returns only `/myPage.jspx` and never `/mobile` or `/tablet` pages.

How can I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't going to work. The `UrlBasedViewResolver` always returns a view regardless the fact if it exists or not. Also your `UrlBasedViewResolver` is always consulted first basically rendering your `LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver` useless.

You also have to let your mobile views use Tiles and make sure that the configured prefix leads to a modified view. I would also suggest to use the `TilesViewResolver` convenience subclass, save you some XML.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.mobile.device.view.LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="mobilePrefix" value="mobile/" />
    <property name="tabletPrefix" value="tablet/" />
</bean>
```

And ofcourse remove your other configured `ViewResolver`.

Comment: I used your code, but I obtain this: Could not resolve view with name 'login' in servlet with name 'appServlet' but in view.xml I added the /tablet/login.jspx..

Comment: Do you actually have a Tiles view named `login`? THe name is `tablet/login.jspx` not `/tablet/login.jspx`.

Comment: Yes I have it: one login page in `/WEB-INF/views/login.jspx` and the other one is in `/WEB-INF/views/tablet/login.jspx` and both with their `view.xml` file

Comment: It is not the actual location it is the name it needs to resolve to (at least what I remember from tiles). The name isn't the same (generally) as the location of the template/view.

Comment: Ok, I solved it.. I writed the wrong name of the view in my .xml  file.. Thank you!